# Add dependency jar entries to jar index (/META-INF/INDEX.LIST)

Tags: java, maven, jar, applet

While developing an applet, I created a maven project with .jar packaging and different .jar dependencies. Now I want to add an archive index (*/META-INF/INDEX.LIST*) to my project's jar that contains not only the entries for this jar but **also the entries of all dependency jar's**.

With the jar command line tool I'd achieve it with

*> jar i myproject.jar dependency1.jar dependency2.jar ...*

Using the maven archive index flag of the maven-jar-plugin only the entries for *myproject.jar* occur in the archive index, not so the entries of the dependency jars:

```
  ...
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <index>true</index>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ...
```

Is there a possibility to include the entries of dependencies into the index file with maven?

Thank you for any hints...

Comment: How did you define the dependencies ? (scope?)

Comment: <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
   <groupId>test.company</groupId>
   <artifactId>applet-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
 </dependency>
  </dependencies>

Comment: You will only see the applet-core artifact in the classpath (MANIFEST.MF) file.

Comment: I got it also working for the project and even the dependency artefacts. I'll post an answer when I'm allowed to ;-)

Comment: I thought it is working but faced another problem: I created a new project, added the archive-index parameter in the maven-jar-plugin config (as shown above) in the pom.xml and created two files: _src/main/resources/a.txt_ and _src/main/resource/test/b.txt_. After a maven install only _a.txt_ occurs in _INDEX.LIST_, _b.txt_ is NOT listed (in contrast, the folder _test_ is shown). I could not find any bug report. Where is my mistake?

Comment: No mistake. According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#Overview, only the files of the root directory and subdirectories (packages) will be listed in _INDEX.LIST_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved it with the following configuration:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <index>true</index>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

With this configuration, all jar files (project and dependencies) are listed in the *MANIFEST.MF's* classpath and their entries (files at directory level and package names according to the *jar index doc*) will occur in *INDEX.LIST*.

**Note #1:** Using both *index* and *addManifest* prior version 2.4 results in the bug described in http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAR-69. So make sure to use version 2.4 of the maven-jar-plugin.

**Note #2:** Due to the bug described in http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-1219, dependencies will occur neither in MANIFEST.MF nor in INDEX.LIST if dependencies are resolved using *Resolve Workspace artifacts* (option of the Eclipse Run configuration). So make sure that you a) first install/deploy all dependencies and b) disable the *Resolve Workspace artifacts* option (or close the dependency project in eclipse) if necessary before building the project with eclipse.

**Note #3:** Do NOT use both the *jar-with-dependencies* (maven-assembly-plugin) and *addClasspath* (maven-jar-plugin), or you'll double all entries in the resulting jar.

**Note #4:** The java *jar* command line tool does also evaluate the MANIFEST.MF's classpath (besides explicit listing of jar files when invoking the tool as shown in my initial example), see the index example of the *jar doc*.

Due to Note #2, I'll investigate into ANT's *jar*...

Many thanks to @khmarbaise pointing my to the right direction :-)

Answer (score 0):

You know that this is not part of the [INDEX.LIST](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html) file cause it contains only classes but not the dependencies. The dependencies should be located into the MANIFEST.MF file instead (As far as i know).

Based on [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html) you won't get that information into the INDEX.LIST file. You can use the MANIFEST.MF file for this.

Comment: INDEX.LIST contains a list of JARs (dependencies) with the info about which classes the JARs contain